# Copy shifts from leap year to non-leap year

Tags: t-sql, copy, leap-year

I need to copy all the shifts from 2012 to 2013 using T-SQL 2008 R2. There are 3 shifts per day. Start date and shift date are always same. end date (for shift c) is the next day.

[image]

As you can see, if I just used dateadd(year, 1, Col), I get 2 sets of records for 2013-02-28. The rows 4, 6 and 8 shouldn't be there (and will cause PK violations). row 8 is wrong as the end time for shift C should be previous calendar day.

I have 67,000-ish rows in total to copy

Only thing I can think of off top of my head is insert to temp table and then somehow identify dupes/incorrect records, delete and then insert back into shifts table. I'm sure there must be a better way

Anyone got a cunning plan?

I'd like to create a general purpose Stored procedure that can copy leap year to non-leap year and vice versa

Regards

Mark

Comment: Can't you do something along the lines of "where datepart(month, start) <> 2 or datepart(day,start) <> 29"

Comment: Use a CTE to generate a set of `Start` and `End` values for the new year and then use a `JOIN` to get the matching values from the current year.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a `DISTINCT` list combined with a `WHERE End > Start`, as in this simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE Shifts(ShiftCode CHAR, ShiftStart DATETIME, ShiftEnd DATETIME);
GO

INSERT Shifts
VALUES('A','2/26/2012 07:00:00','2/26/2012 15:00:00')
, ('B','2/26/2012 15:00:00','2/26/2012 23:00:00')
, ('C','2/26/2012 23:00:00','2/27/2012 07:00:00')
, ('A','2/27/2012 07:00:00','2/27/2012 15:00:00')
, ('B','2/27/2012 15:00:00','2/27/2012 23:00:00')
, ('C','2/27/2012 23:00:00','2/28/2012 07:00:00')
, ('A','2/28/2012 07:00:00','2/28/2012 15:00:00')
, ('B','2/28/2012 15:00:00','2/28/2012 23:00:00')
, ('C','2/28/2012 23:00:00','2/29/2012 07:00:00')
, ('A','2/29/2012 07:00:00','2/29/2012 15:00:00')
, ('B','2/29/2012 15:00:00','2/29/2012 23:00:00')
, ('C','2/29/2012 23:00:00','3/1/2012 07:00:00')
, ('A','3/1/2012 07:00:00','3/1/2012 15:00:00')
, ('B','3/1/2012 15:00:00','3/1/2012 23:00:00')
, ('C','3/1/2012 23:00:00','3/2/2012 07:00:00');
GO

SELECT DISTINCT ShiftCode
, ShiftStart = DATEADD(YYYY,1,ShiftStart)
, ShiftEnd = DATEADD(YYYY,1,ShiftEnd)
FROM Shifts
WHERE DATEADD(YYYY,1,ShiftEnd) > DATEADD(YYYY,1,ShiftStart)
ORDER BY DATEADD(YYYY,1,ShiftStart), ShiftCode
GO
```

Result:

```
A         2013-02-26 07:00:00.000 2013-02-26 15:00:00.000
B         2013-02-26 15:00:00.000 2013-02-26 23:00:00.000
C         2013-02-26 23:00:00.000 2013-02-27 07:00:00.000
A         2013-02-27 07:00:00.000 2013-02-27 15:00:00.000
B         2013-02-27 15:00:00.000 2013-02-27 23:00:00.000
C         2013-02-27 23:00:00.000 2013-02-28 07:00:00.000
A         2013-02-28 07:00:00.000 2013-02-28 15:00:00.000
B         2013-02-28 15:00:00.000 2013-02-28 23:00:00.000
C         2013-02-28 23:00:00.000 2013-03-01 07:00:00.000
A         2013-03-01 07:00:00.000 2013-03-01 15:00:00.000
B         2013-03-01 15:00:00.000 2013-03-01 23:00:00.000
C         2013-03-01 23:00:00.000 2013-03-02 07:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out BUT then found some resources were missing shifts for 2012

Ended up creating with tally table and just doing fresh inserts for every shift for the year

```
SELECT
                    rh.PlanPressID
                    ,DATEADD(hh,(24 / @NoOfShifts) * (t.N - 1),@StartDateTime) AS ShiftStart
                   ,DATEADD(hh,(24 / @NoOfShifts) * (t.N),@StartDateTime) AS ShiftEnd
                   ,CHAR((t.N - 1) % @NoOfShifts + 65) AS ShiftCode
                   ,DATEADD(dd,0,DATEDIFF(dd,0,DATEADD(hh,(24 / @NoOfShifts) * (t.N - 1),@StartDateTime))) AS ShiftDate
                   ,0 AS Personnel
                  FROM
                    dbo.Tally t
                  CROSS JOIN dbo.ResourceHeader AS rh
```